# SlimDx inside WPF - Slow rendering

Tags: wpf, slimdx

I have a slimDx win forms application that renders several thousand objects to the screen over the course of several thousand drawcalls. On my machine, it quite happily does this at around 150 FPS.

I then tried to port this to a WPF application, by having WPF host the slimdx content.

The first method was to use the approach given by the SlimDx samples, in which they use a shared texture that can be written to by SlimDx and presented by WPF. When I try this, I get a frame rate of around 12-14 for the same amount of work. I believe this is due to them doing the SlimDx rendering on the CompositionTarget.Rendering event that caps out at around 60FPS. Whereas in a Win32/Forms application you have access to the MessageLoop and are able to render whenever there are no messages to process (i.e during the idle time), using the CompositionTarget.Render you render at the pace of WPF, and so you don't get to use this "idle time" to your advantage, the result being you'll get 60 FPS at best - minus however long it takes to do what you're doing in the CompositionTarget.Rendering event handler, which I believe is why I get the low FPS.

I then tried by using the WindowsFormsHost object to host the SlimDx Renderform, and using a winforms Timer as the "Render Tick", but alas I have the same problem, I only seem to get the event at best at a rate of around 60 FPS. When I then add in the rendering code, Im back to the low fps.

How can I get a similar performance to that that of the bare bones win forms App? (I don't need the 150fps, I just need it to be above 30FPS)

i don't think pasting any code here would be helpful as there is too much, but I can upload the project if it helps